# Android: Launch Calculator when pressing button

Tags: android, calculator

I'm developing an app and I need that when the user clicks on the calculator button it launches the android calculator. Is there a way of doing this or do I need to create a calculator myself?

In case I have to create the calculator myself and to only show in a specific part of the screen like the android calculator what type of thing is this one (showdialog, popup, toast etc)?

Comment: There is definitely a way, like [this](http://sagistech.blogspot.ca/2010/08/starting-android-calculator.html) However, you can rarely depend on an outside app to be there, OEMs can change anything, including default apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the calculator app like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); 
startActivity(i);
```

With this you are starting an Activity in an other package, `setClassName(...)` takes the package and the class as a parameter.

Note that this will not work on devices that do not use the default calculator app.

Comment: Hi Ahmad thank you very much, I've tried and declared in the manifest. However it says that the new intent is not declared in the manifest. It says unable to find com.android.calculator2.com/android.calculator.Calculator. How to declare this in the manifest with the "/" because "/" is not allowed in the manifest. Thank you

Comment: You don't have to declare anything for this in your manifest :)